# $web.Groups returns empty Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, groups

I have a site collection under which i have created a sub-site with unique permissions,

this sub-site has following groups

```
Community Site Owners  SharePoint Group     Full Control

Project Site Members   SharePoint Group     Contribute

Project Site Owners    SharePoint Group     Full Control

Project Site Visitors  SharePoint Group     Read
```

Note: There is no user peresent in any of these groups

I am running a powershell script

```
$websites = Get-SPWeb "http://XYZ/*"
foreach($web in $websites)
{
    Write-Host  "`r`n`r`n---------------------------------"$web.Title ":" $web.Url "---------------------------------"

    $groups = $web.Groups
    Write-Host $groups.Count
    foreach($grp in $groups)
    {
     $Count++
         Write-Host  "`r`n`r`n---------------------------------`r`n" $Count ":" $grp.Name "`r`n---------------------------------"
       if($grp.Name -ne "NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users"){
             GetUsersRecursive $web $grp
        }
    }
 }
```

Now When my sub-site doesn't have user in any of groups my `$groups.Count` is `0` and ***$web.Title is not printed***

OUTPUT When no user in Group

```
---------------------------------  : http://XYZ/projectsite ---------------------------------
0
```

but when I add a user the output shows all groups and even prints the Title property of $web

OUTPUT when a single user is added to one of the groups of sub-site

```
--------------------------------- Project Site : http://XYZ/projectsite ---------------------------------
4


---------------------------------
 1 : Community Site Owners 
---------------------------------


---------------------------------
 2 : Project Site Members 
---------------------------------
User1


---------------------------------
 3 : Project Site Owners 
---------------------------------



---------------------------------
 4 : Project Site Visitors 
---------------------------------
```

I am trying to understand why this happens, while if i implement same logic in C# i am able to retrieve everything properly. Can someone explain this behaviour of powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Is it that your user does not have permission to the site because it's not in any of the groups.

As a test add the user that is running the powershell script as site collection admin, just to see if you can then see the groups ok.

Comment: No i don't think so because even if this user is not present in any of the groups it would still print the output for other user, I suppose this is not user specific behaviour, I am running code in powershell using site collection admin account.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are getting subwebs. It should be foreach($web in $websites.Webs). That aside you could try using the AssociatedGroups property. In theory Groups should only return groups that have security roles assigned while  AssociatedGroups will return all groups whether they have roles assigned or not.

Edit:
When I tested this with two sites a and b. Three unique groups both site not inheriting security. It works fine:

```
--------------------------------- b : http://test/sites/res/b ---------------------------------
3


---------------------------------
 3 : Empty Group a
---------------------------------


---------------------------------
 4 : Empty Group B
---------------------------------


---------------------------------
 5 : Empty Group C
---------------------------------


--------------------------------- a : http://test/sites/res/a ---------------------------------
3


---------------------------------
 6 : Some Group 2
---------------------------------


---------------------------------
 7 : Some group One
---------------------------------


---------------------------------
 8 : Some Group three
---------------------------------
```

Comment: When your URL is "http ://something/* (don't miss asterisk) it will iterate all sites underneath your http: //something  I tried with AssociatedGroups but the output is same, no change

Comment: Sorry missed the *. I tried this on a new site collection in 2013 sp1 with a few sub sites and it worked as expected... What version of SP are you using?

Comment: To be clear I have 3 groups with no members and they all displayed correctly.

Comment: 1. have you applied "Unique permissions" for subsites? 2.These groups may not be AssociatedOwner/AssociatedMember/AssociatedVisitors, they can be any custom created groups. 3. I am using SP2013 SP1  4.Can you justify me getting $web.Title is not printed?. This is so odd of SharePoint

Comment: 1. Yes 2. They aren't. See my edit.  4. sorry I have no idea. Maybe try using ISE and then debug line by line.